# Centering my Title DIV

Tags: css

http://we-live.in/the_sierra - Towards the bottom of the page I have a div which contains an image of grass. How can I get the grass image to be centered horizontally on the page?

> ok i got it centered
>   now i need to move it lower down on the page

thanks

Comment: It would be more helpful if you provided the code in question instead of just a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS, add the following

```
background-position:center top;
```

to the following:

```
#title{
  width:940;
  height:145px;
  display:block;
  background-image:url(images/header.jpg)
}
```

Additionally, you can also add the following

```
margin:auto;
```

But that may not be necessary if you are simply wanting the background image (the grass image) to be centered.

Comment: #title {
background-image:url(imgs/new_neighborrow.png);
background-position:center top;
display:block;
height:145px;
width:940px;
}

i checked with firebug and its still to the left-- ill try the automargin-- thanks!

Comment: That's the wrong `#title` declaration. Aren't you talking about the one that has `header.jpg` as the background?

Comment: ok i got it centered and identified the right declaration... but now if i try to put it at the bottom with the footer it messes everything up? thanks in advance not sure if the site is for this type of little stuff im just learning- ill be sure to read through the faq and best practices- thanks

Comment: If the problem is fixed, you should accept my answer. If you have a new problem, you should create a new question :)